# Any outstanding examples of a flight reservation system UI?

Tags: usability, layout

I am developing a flight reservation/booking system for a corporate client. Does anyone have any good examples of an outstanding UI for a flight reservation/booking system?

Comment: That's a very broad question about a potentially very complex process. Is there a particular user experience challenge you're facing?

Comment: No Matt. I am just trying to get a feel for what people think are the best user experience when it comes to flight reservations. I want to use the examples suggested as a starting point for my own design.

Comment: This isn't a question for SE. A forum is probably better for this. Asking for a list of references will likely get your question flagged. Like Matt said, make this a specific question. (Ex: Why doesn't this design work for flight booking? or How should I specialize my specific design for corporations?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is this french startup, Capitaine Train (http://www.capitainetrain.com/), which is making booking (for trains) much easier. I tried it and it's amazing if you compare to regular voyages-sncf.com website.

Ok it's for train, but I guess you can find great inspiration there as well.
Hope it helps.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [hipmunk?](http://www.hipmunk.com/). Why don't you book a flight (as far as you can get without creating an account) with [BA](http://www.britishairways.com/travel/home/public/en_gb?cookiesAccepted=newvispop), [easyJet](http://www.easyjet.com/en) or [Ryanair](http://www.ryanair.com/en)? Alternatively use [google  to conduct your research.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=flight+reservation+UI&oq=flight+reservation+UI&gs_l=serp.3...21309.21376.0.22248.2.2.0.0.0.0.74.124.2.2.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.WvsXOQEIMTo)

Answer (score 0):

In line with the idea that the best interfaces are the least interfaces, I think [Kayak Connect](http://www.tnooz.com/2010/06/03/mobile/revealed-first-details-of-kayak-booking-assistant/) is one of the friendliest UIs. Using information like name, birthdate, and credit card number provided ahead of time, it allows users to book flights with just the bare minimum of work.